# Random "Enlisted connection used without active transaction" errors

Tags: quarkus, agroal

In my Quarkus app I get `Enlisted connection used without active transaction` errors around once a day (on a public API used quite a lot).

It seems to come from Agroal (here https://github.com/agroal/agroal/blob/master/agroal-pool/src/main/java/io/agroal/pool/ConnectionHandler.java#L393).

According to the stack trace it fails at various places in REST endpoints annotated with `@Transactional`.

In PostgreSQL I only get the following:

```
ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request
```

Comment: I have the same problem when using Kafka Emitter and sending events during the Transactional scope. And also it happens not every time, but each 10-15 invocations.

Comment: @T_E_M_A I provided a workaround in this issue: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/21948

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around this issue by firing an event which is listened in a TransactionPhase.AFTER_SUCCESS method (and this method send the Kafka message).